# Android ViewPager not Showing

Tags: java, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-include

I am trying to make a little app to try out some things for a bigger app I am developing. I want to add a viewpager that displays four images, I developed this viewpager alone and it worked, but when I tried to add it to my other app (with just a couple of buttons) with the  tag, it does not show anything and I am really stuck in here. Is possible to add the Viewpager this way? Honestly I don't have that much experience in Java, I usually program only C and Assembler and I will be reaaally glad if you could help me.

This is the xml file with the button and the include:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculo Rapido"
    android:id="@+id/btcr"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.16"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculo Avanzado"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btcr" />

<include layout="@layout/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:translationZ="15dp" />
```

Now, the MainActivity, which holds the button activity because I kept the Viewpager inside an Activity that's linked with the viewpager original layout

```
Button siguiente;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    siguiente = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btcr);
    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(siguiente);
        }
    });
}
```

And lastly, the code for the mainpager main activity, this uses a CustomPagerAdapter saved in another java class. As I told before, this viewpager does work alone, but when I try to implement it here, with the /include tag, it doesn't show anything.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
private static int currentPage = 0;
private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
Button siguiente;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // == Setting up the ViewPager ==

    mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++);

            if (currentPage == 5) {
                currentPage = 0;
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, false);
            }
        }
    };
    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 2000, 2000);

}
```

Sorry if it is too long guys, but I am a little frustrated, I have tried a lot of things but it isn't working yet. Either the buttons do their thing and the ViewPager doesn't work or the ViewPager works but the buttons are dead.

I will reaaally aprecciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, what I needed was just the simple solution. I had to put the viewpager on my activity's layout file as another object, just configuring its size and position. And then, on my onCreate I pasted the code of my functioning ViewPager. Quite simple, without requiring another layouts :)

Answer (score 0):

create a new xml file inside `layout` folder and name it `secondactivity.xml`

and put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/pager">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now inside your `Main2Activity.class`

change

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

to

`setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);`

And remove the `include` from your previous xml

Comment: I have another 3 xml layouts. One with a splash screen, another empty one for testing (that my buttons actually jumped to this layout) and one that provides the elements for the View Pager. And I have another three activities, the splash screen, the one that allows buttons to move through layers and the one that made the viewpager work (draws the image, creates the routine, etc). Thanks for the help ebyt, I am implementing your solution right now :)